# ERR invalid character '}' looking for beginning of object key string: goroutine 20932 in kiali

Tags: istio, kiali, istio-kiali

I am trying to install Prometheus and Kiali using Istio sample addons. I modifies the file to add `nodePort` for Service and changed `imagePullPolicy` to `IfNotPresent` for Kiali container. The pod comes up, but I am unable to view the graph. It gives the following error:

```
ERR invalid character '}' looking for beginning of object key string: goroutine 20932
```

Kiali pod gives the following stack trace:

```
invalid character '}' looking for beginning of object key string
Additional Detail:
goroutine 2066 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack(0xc00173aa80, 0x40, 0xc0020d0cc0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x9f
github.com/kiali/kiali/handlers.handlePanic(0x1d5bad0, 0xc001819dc0)
    /home/fedora/workspace/kiali-workflow/kiali-release/src/github.com/kiali/kiali/handlers/graph.go:86 +0x185
panic(0x1841540, 0xc0020d0cc0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:965 +0x1b9
github.com/kiali/kiali/graph.CheckError(...)
    /home/fedora/workspace/kiali-workflow/kiali-release/src/github.com/kiali/kiali/graph/util.go:38
github.com/kiali/kiali/graph/telemetry/istio/appender.ServiceEntryAppender.AppendGraph(0xc000734f90, 0xc0008ae8f7, 0xc, 0xc000735380, 0xc0007352c0, 0xc0020d0a80)
    /home/fedora/workspace/kiali-workflow/kiali-release/src/github.com/kiali/kiali/graph/telemetry/istio/appender/service_entry.go:59 +0x1c6
github.com/kiali/kiali/graph/telemetry/istio.BuildNamespacesTrafficMap(0xc000734f90, 0x0, 0xc0020ed6d0, 0x5, 0x5, 0x100, 0xc000734ea0, 0xdf8475800, 0xc0008ae8f7, 0xc, ...)
    /home/fedora/workspace/kiali-workflow/kiali-release/src/github.com/kiali/kiali/graph/telemetry/istio/istio.go:54 +0x282
github.com/kiali/kiali/graph/api.graphNamespacesIstio(0xc001e625a0, 0xc000d95c00, 0x1af6a6c, 0x9, 0x1af1831, 0x5, 0xc0008ae939, 0x3, 0xdf8475800, 0xc0008ae8f7, ...)
    /home/fedora/workspace/kiali-workflow/kiali-release/src/github.com/kiali/kiali/graph/api/api.go:44 +0xb8
github.com/kiali/kiali/graph/api.GraphNamespaces(0xc001e625a0, 0x1af6a6c, 0x9, 0x1af1831, 0x5, 0xc0008ae939, 0x3, 0xdf8475800, 0xc0008ae8f7, 0xc, ...)
    /home/fedora/workspace/kiali-workflow/kiali-release/src/github.com/kiali/kiali/graph/api/api.go:26 +0x178
github.com/kiali/kiali/handlers.GraphNamespaces(0x1d5bad0, 0xc001819dc0, 0xc000eecc00)
    /home/fedora/workspace/kiali-workflow/kiali-release/src/github.com/kiali/kiali/handlers/graph.go:51 +0x13c
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x1bc10a0, 0x1d5bad0, 0xc001819dc0, 0xc000eecc00)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2069 +0x44
github.com/kiali/kiali/routing.metricHandler.func1(0x1d5bad0, 0xc001819dc0, 0xc000eecc00)
    /home/fedora/workspace/kiali-workflow/kiali-release/src/github.com/kiali/kiali/routing/router.go:92 +0xa3
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc000132fc0, 0x1d5bad0, 0xc001819dc0, 0xc000eecc00)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2069 +0x44
github.com/kiali/kiali/handlers.AuthenticationHandler.Handle.func1(0x1d5bad0, 0xc001819dc0, 0xc000eecb00)
    /home/fedora/workspace/kiali-workflow/kiali-release/src/github.com/kiali/kiali/handlers/authentication.go:649 +0x1f7
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc000689230, 0x1d5bad0, 0xc001819dc0, 0xc000eecb00)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2069 +0x44
github.com/kiali/kiali/server.plainHttpMiddleware.func1(0x1d5bad0, 0xc001819dc0, 0xc000eecb00)
    /home/fedora/workspace/kiali-workflow/kiali-release/src/github.com/kiali/kiali/server/server.go:127 +0x6c
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc00061d740, 0x1d5bad0, 0xc001819dc0, 0xc000eecb00)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2069 +0x44
github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc00031c0c0, 0x1d5bad0, 0xc001819dc0, 0xc000eec500)
    /home/fedora/workspace/kiali-workflow/kiali-release/pkg/mod/github.com/gorilla/mux@v1.7.4/mux.go:210 +0xd3
github.com/NYTimes/gziphandler.GzipHandlerWithOpts.func1.1(0x1d5b9e0, 0xc00075c460, 0xc000eec500)
    /home/fedora/workspace/kiali-workflow/kiali-release/pkg/mod/github.com/!n!y!times/gziphandler@v1.1.1/gzip.go:336 +0x22d
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0xc00025e510, 0x1d5b9e0, 0xc00075c460, 0xc000eec500)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2069 +0x44
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0xc00014f800, 0x1d5b9e0, 0xc00075c460, 0xc000eec500)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2448 +0x1ad
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc00021c000, 0x1d5b9e0, 0xc00075c460, 0xc000eec500)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2887 +0xa3
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0002c65a0, 0x1d5f6b8, 0xc00131fa40)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1952 +0x8cd
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:3013 +0x39b
```

Version details:

- Kubernetes: 1.21.1
- Istio: 1.10.0
- Prometheus: 2.24.0
- Kiali: 1.34

Edit: Adding manifest files used for deployment.

Kiali Configmap:

```
# Source: kiali-server/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: kiali
  namespace: istio-system
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: kiali-server-1.34.0
    app: kiali
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kiali
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kiali-server
    version: "v1.34.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "v1.34.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: "kiali"
data:
  config.yaml: |
    auth:
      openid: {}
      openshift:
        client_id_prefix: kiali
      strategy: anonymous
    deployment:
      accessible_namespaces:
      - '**'
      additional_service_yaml: {}
      affinity:
        node: {}
        pod: {}
        pod_anti: {}
      custom_dashboards:
        excludes:
        - ""
        includes:
        - '*'
      hpa:
        api_version: autoscaling/v2beta2
        spec: {}
      image_name: quay.io/kiali/kiali
      image_pull_policy: IfNotPresent
      image_pull_secrets: []
      image_version: v1.34
      ingress_enabled: false
      logger:
        log_format: text
        log_level: info
        sampler_rate: "1"
        time_field_format: 2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00
      namespace: istio-system
      node_selector: {}
      override_ingress_yaml:
        metadata: {}
      pod_annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
      pod_labels: {}
      priority_class_name: ""
      replicas: 1
      resources: {}
      secret_name: kiali
      service_annotations: {}
      service_type: ""
      tolerations: []
      version_label: v1.34.0
      view_only_mode: false
    external_services:
      custom_dashboards:
        enabled: true
    identity:
      cert_file: ""
      private_key_file: ""
    istio_namespace: istio-system
    login_token:
      signing_key: CHANGEME
    server:
      metrics_enabled: true
      metrics_port: 9090
      port: 20001
      web_root: /kiali
---
# Source: kiali-server/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kiali
  namespace: istio-system
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: kiali-server-1.34.0
    app: kiali
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kiali
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kiali-server
    version: "v1.34.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "v1.34.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: "kiali"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: kiali
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: kiali-server
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      name: kiali
      labels:
        helm.sh/chart: kiali-server-1.34.0
        app: kiali
        app.kubernetes.io/name: kiali
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: kiali-server
        version: "v1.34.0"
        app.kubernetes.io/version: "v1.34.0"
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: "kiali"
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        prometheus.io/port: "9090"
        kiali.io/runtimes: go,kiali
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: kiali
      containers:
      - image: "quay.io/kiali/kiali:v1.34"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: kiali
        command:
        - "/opt/kiali/kiali"
        - "-config"
        - "/kiali-configuration/config.yaml"
        ports:
        - name: api-port
          containerPort: 20001
        - name: http-metrics
          containerPort: 9090
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /kiali/healthz
            port: api-port
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 30
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /kiali/healthz
            port: api-port
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 30
        env:
        - name: ACTIVE_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: LOG_LEVEL
          value: "info"
        - name: LOG_FORMAT
          value: "text"
        - name: LOG_TIME_FIELD_FORMAT
          value: "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00" 
        - name: LOG_SAMPLER_RATE
          value: "1"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: kiali-configuration
          mountPath: "/kiali-configuration"
        - name: kiali-cert
          mountPath: "/kiali-cert"
        - name: kiali-secret
          mountPath: "/kiali-secret"
      volumes:
      - name: kiali-configuration
        configMap:
          name: kiali
      - name: kiali-cert
        secret:
          secretName: istio.kiali-service-account
          optional: true
      - name: kiali-secret
        secret:
          secretName: kiali
          optional: true
---
# Source: kiali-server/templates/service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kiali
  namespace: istio-system
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: kiali-server-1.34.0
    app: kiali
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kiali
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kiali-server
    version: "v1.34.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "v1.34.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: "kiali"
  annotations:
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 20001
    nodePort: 31334
  - name: http-metrics
    protocol: TCP
    port: 9090
    nodePort: 31335
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kiali
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kiali-server
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Prometheus:

```
# Source: prometheus/templates/server/cm.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    component: "server"
    app: prometheus
    release: prometheus
    chart: prometheus-13.6.0
    heritage: Helm
  name: prometheus
  namespace: istio-system
data:
  alerting_rules.yml: |
    groups:
    - name: Alerts
      rules:
      - alert: High Pod Memory
        expr: sum(container_memory_usage_bytes) > 1
        for: 5m
        labels:
          severity: slack
        annotations:
          summary: High Memory Usage
  alerts: |
    {}
  prometheus.yml: |
    global:
      evaluation_interval: 1m
      scrape_interval: 15s
      scrape_timeout: 10s
    rule_files:
    - /etc/config/recording_rules.yml
    - /etc/config/alerting_rules.yml
    - /etc/config/rules
    - /etc/config/alerts
    alerting:
      alertmanagers:
        - scheme: http
          static_configs:
            - targets:
              - "alertmanager:9093"
    scrape_configs:
    - job_name: prometheus
      static_configs:
      - targets:
        - localhost:9090
    - bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
      job_name: kubernetes-apiservers
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints
      relabel_configs:
      - action: keep
        regex: default;kubernetes;https
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_name
        - __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name
      scheme: https
      tls_config:
        ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        insecure_skip_verify: true
    - bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
      job_name: kubernetes-nodes
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: node
      relabel_configs:
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
      - replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
        target_label: __address__
      - regex: (.+)
        replacement: /api/v1/nodes/$1/proxy/metrics
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_node_name
        target_label: __metrics_path__
      scheme: https
      tls_config:
        ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        insecure_skip_verify: true
    - bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
      job_name: kubernetes-nodes-cadvisor
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: node
      relabel_configs:
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
      - replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
        target_label: __address__
      - regex: (.+)
        replacement: /api/v1/nodes/$1/proxy/metrics/cadvisor
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_node_name
        target_label: __metrics_path__
      scheme: https
      tls_config:
        ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        insecure_skip_verify: true
    - job_name: kubernetes-service-endpoints
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints
      relabel_configs:
      - action: keep
        regex: true
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape
      - action: replace
        regex: (https?)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme
        target_label: __scheme__
      - action: replace
        regex: (.+)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path
        target_label: __metrics_path__
      - action: replace
        regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
        replacement: $1:$2
        source_labels:
        - __address__
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port
        target_label: __address__
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
        target_label: kubernetes_namespace
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_name
        target_label: kubernetes_name
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name
        target_label: kubernetes_node
    - job_name: kubernetes-service-endpoints-slow
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints
      relabel_configs:
      - action: keep
        regex: true
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape_slow
      - action: replace
        regex: (https?)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme
        target_label: __scheme__
      - action: replace
        regex: (.+)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path
        target_label: __metrics_path__
      - action: replace
        regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
        replacement: $1:$2
        source_labels:
        - __address__
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port
        target_label: __address__
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
        target_label: kubernetes_namespace
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_name
        target_label: kubernetes_name
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name
        target_label: kubernetes_node
      scrape_interval: 5m
      scrape_timeout: 30s
    - honor_labels: true
      job_name: prometheus-pushgateway
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: service
      relabel_configs:
      - action: keep
        regex: pushgateway
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_probe
    - job_name: kubernetes-services
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: service
      metrics_path: /probe
      params:
        module:
        - http_2xx
      relabel_configs:
      - action: keep
        regex: true
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_probe
      - source_labels:
        - __address__
        target_label: __param_target
      - replacement: blackbox
        target_label: __address__
      - source_labels:
        - __param_target
        target_label: instance
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
      - source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
        target_label: kubernetes_namespace
      - source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_service_name
        target_label: kubernetes_name
    - job_name: kubernetes-pods
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
      relabel_configs:
      - action: keep
        regex: true
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape
      - action: replace
        regex: (https?)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme
        target_label: __scheme__
      - action: replace
        regex: (.+)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path
        target_label: __metrics_path__
      - action: replace
        regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
        replacement: $1:$2
        source_labels:
        - __address__
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port
        target_label: __address__
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
        target_label: kubernetes_namespace
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_name
        target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
      - action: drop
        regex: Pending|Succeeded|Failed
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_phase
    - job_name: kubernetes-pods-slow
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
      relabel_configs:
      - action: keep
        regex: true
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape_slow
      - action: replace
        regex: (https?)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme
        target_label: __scheme__
      - action: replace
        regex: (.+)
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path
        target_label: __metrics_path__
      - action: replace
        regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
        replacement: $1:$2
        source_labels:
        - __address__
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port
        target_label: __address__
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
        target_label: kubernetes_namespace
      - action: replace
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_name
        target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
      - action: drop
        regex: Pending|Succeeded|Failed
        source_labels:
        - __meta_kubernetes_pod_phase
      scrape_interval: 5m
      scrape_timeout: 30s
  recording_rules.yml: |
    {}
  rules: |
    {}
---
# Source: prometheus/templates/server/deploy.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    component: "server"
    app: prometheus
    release: prometheus
    chart: prometheus-13.6.0
    heritage: Helm
  name: prometheus
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: "server"
      app: prometheus
      release: prometheus
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
      labels:
        component: "server"
        app: prometheus
        release: prometheus
        chart: prometheus-13.6.0
        heritage: Helm
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: prometheus
      containers:
        - name: prometheus-server-configmap-reload
          image: "jimmidyson/configmap-reload:v0.5.0"
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          args:
            - --volume-dir=/etc/config
            - --webhook-url=http://127.0.0.1:9090/-/reload
          resources:
            {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/config
              readOnly: true

        - name: prometheus-server
          image: "prom/prometheus:v2.24.0"
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          args:
            - --storage.tsdb.retention.time=15d
            - --config.file=/etc/config/prometheus.yml
            - --storage.tsdb.path=/data
            - --web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries
            - --web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles
            - --web.enable-lifecycle
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
              #readinessProbe:
              #httpGet:
              #path: /-/ready
              #port: 9090
              #initialDelaySeconds: 0
              #periodSeconds: 5
              #timeoutSeconds: 4
              #failureThreshold: 3
              #successThreshold: 1
              #livenessProbe:
              #httpGet:
              #path: /-/healthy
              #port: 9090
              #initialDelaySeconds: 30
              #periodSeconds: 15
              #timeoutSeconds: 10
              #failureThreshold: 3
              #successThreshold: 1
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /etc/config
            - name: storage-volume
              mountPath: /data
              subPath: ""
      hostNetwork: false
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 65534
        runAsGroup: 65534
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 65534
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: prometheus
        - name: storage-volume
          emptyDir:
            {}
---
# Source: prometheus/templates/server/service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    component: "server"
    app: prometheus
    release: prometheus
    chart: prometheus-13.6.0
    heritage: Helm
  name: prometheus
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 9090
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9090
      nodePort: 31333
  selector:
    component: "server"
    app: prometheus
    release: prometheus
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: Did you use the manifest included with Istio download? Did you change anything else? Mind sharing the yaml you used do deploy Kiali?

Comment: Added the deployment files for kiali and prometheus.

Comment: What about Service manifests? You said you changed those to NodePort, please also include those.

Comment: Added service manifests as well.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need LoadBalencer service for Kiali and Prometheus?

Comment: There is no particular reason. I can switch to NodePort too, if required. I am not clear as to how kiali connects to prometheus, since there is no configuration provided mentioning prometheus co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no particular reason for `LoadBalancer` I would recommend reverting those manifests back to the original, provided with Istio.

If you want to access dashboard you can do so by issuing

```text
istioctl dashboard kiali
```

for Kiali, or

```
istioctl dashboard prometheus
```

for Prometheus.

Optionally you can expose those dashboards using Istio `Gateway` and `VirtualService`. More details are available [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/gateways/).

However, I would not recommend exposing Kiali and Prometheus to outside, as it creates a huge security risk.

Comment: How to the method of exposing cause '}' issue? Even if I keep the services as default, I still get the same issue. I am unable to connect how kiali and prometheus' k8s service cause this issue?

Comment: Did you deploy all resources in original yaml files, or just ConfigMap, Deployment and Service?

Comment: I deployed all the resources present in the kiali and prometheus file that comes with istio. Couldn't paste the entire file as length exceeds max characters allowed in question.

Comment: Well, at this point I think I tried everything, and I can't replicate your issue. Can you just delete those resources and redeploy them again?

Comment: Sure, will try to apply the istio provided manifests without any modification once.

Comment: @AbhinavSharma any updates?

Comment: I tried to redeploy manifests without modification for kiali, prometheus and grafana, but still got the same error.

Comment: The issue was solved. I reapplied the istio-sidecar-injector configmap. (Earlier resource limits were removed from this file). After that restarted the istiod pod and kiali. Post that, graphs started appearing and the issue was resolved.